# FrameBuffers with Depth attachment not working

Tags: java, opengl, framebuffer, opengl-3

Today I was working with FrameBuffers , and stuff like that. I did make it , and it's working. But one small problem: GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 works , but GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT don't. Code is the same , I just change attachment mode. I'm having Depth buffer as render buffer , if it's not in frame buffer ( rendering to texture without depth buffer , just image ). But with Depth att. I disable it. Code:

```
public void setAsFramebuffer(int num,int att, boolean b) {  
    if (frameBuffer == 0) frameBuffer = GL30.glGenFramebuffers();           
    GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);       
    GL30.glFramebufferTexture2D(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, att, GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, id[num], 0);

    if (att == GL30.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT) { //TODO: add pen mode
        GL20.glDrawBuffers(GL11.GL_NONE);
    } else {
        GL20.glDrawBuffers(att);
    }

    if (GL30.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER) != GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE) {
        String msg;
        boolean crash = true;
        switch (GL30.glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER)) {
            case GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNDEFINED                      : msg = "The default framebuffer does not exist.";
            case GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_ATTACHMENT          : msg = "Some of framebuffers attachment points are framebuffer incomplete.";
            case GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MISSING_ATTACHMENT  : msg = "Framebuffer dosent have any attached images.";
            case GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_DRAW_BUFFER         : msg = "Value of GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_TYPE is GL_NONE for any color attachment point(s) named by GL_DRAW_BUFFERi.";
            case GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_READ_BUFFER         : msg = "Value of GL_FRAMEBUFFER_ATTACHMENT_OBJECT_TYPE is GL_NONE for the color attachment point named by GL_READ_BUFFER";
            case GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE         : msg = "GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_MULTISAMPLE";
            case GL30.GL_RENDERBUFFER_SAMPLES                       : msg = "GL_RENDERBUFFER_SAMPLES ";
            case GL32.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_LAYER_TARGETS       : msg = "GL_FRAMEBUFFER_INCOMPLETE_LAYER_TARGETS";

            case GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNSUPPORTED                    : msg = "Framebuffers not supported by Grahpics card."; crash = false;
            default: msg = "unknown! Maybe GL error? "; crash = true; CoreEngine.checkForGLErrors();
        }
        System.out.println("Framebuffer error! Someting is bad happened here...Error: "+msg);
        if (crash) System.exit(0);
    }

    if(b) this.setupDepthRenderBuffer();

    GL30.glBindFramebuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
}

public void setupDepthRenderBuffer() {
    renderBuffer = GL30.glGenRenderbuffers();
    GL30.glBindRenderbuffer(GL30.GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer);
    GL30.glRenderbufferStorage(GL30.GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL11.GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, width[0], height[0]);
    GL30.glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL30.GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL30.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL30.GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffer);
}
```

Does Dept att. also needs color att.? Or did I mess up something?

Oh, and it's saying what its unknown error. I didn't see anything else in docs , just that errors.

Texture initialization:

```
public void loadTexture(int glRepeat, int filter, int glTexture2d,
        int width, int height, ByteBuffer buffer) {
    this.width[0] = width;
    this.height[0] = height;

    if(buffer == EMPTRY_PICTURE) buffer = Util.createByteBuffer(width*height*4);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, glRepeat);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, glRepeat);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, filter);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, filter);

    glTexImage2D(glTexture2d, 0, GL_RGBA8, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

    if (filter == GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_NEAREST ||
            filter == GL_NEAREST_MIPMAP_LINEAR ||
            filter == GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_NEAREST ||
            filter == GL_LINEAR_MIPMAP_LINEAR) 
    {
        GL30.glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        float ani;
        ani = glGetFloat(GL_MAX_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT);
        glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_ANISOTROPY_EXT,Math.min(ani,8f));             
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is really confusing. The line `if (att == GL30.GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT)` suggests that this function might be called with `att == GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT`. In that case, you attach a _texture_ as depth attachment. And it is unclear if the texure you use is depth-renderable. Then you check for the framebuffer status, and _after that_, you attach a _renberbuffer_ as depth buffer, if `b` is true, and never check the staus of the final setup of your framebuffer. Please provide more code (how is this stuff called, how are the texures generates), so that an can follow what is actually going on.

Comment: @derhass B will be always false , if att is DEPTH_ATTACHMENT. B only true if texture without frame buffer , so we will need seperate buffer for it.

Comment: Well, as I said: make sure that the texture you are trying  to use as depth attachment is actually depth-renderabl. YOu cannot use a standard RGB(A) texture for that.

Comment: Then what i need to use?

Comment: A texture with some  `GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT` internal format might be a good start. But you should be aware that this texture will not be color-renderable then. You should specify what you actually plan to do with the depth texture.

Comment: I will use it only for shadows

Comment: OK, that's one of the main usages of depth textures. You should probably look for some tutorial on shadow mapping, as it will explain the setup and usage of such textures.

Comment: @derhass soo , its working but OpenGL cant render depth textures? That is what you want to say?

Comment: not exactly. By default, depth textures are treated like GL_RED textures. But depth textures can also be configured to use the `TEXTURE_COMPARE` modes (and only depth textures can be used that way).

Comment: What "depth-renderable" and "color-renderable" means is that you just  need a color-renderbale format for color attachments, and a depth-renderable format for depth attachments, you cannot mix the two.